# My Asus laptop has been giving me a Yellow exclamation when all my other computer's internet is perfectly fine

Tags: wireless-networking, asus-laptop

OKAY. I just bought a beautiful looking Asus. It's so nice, but it fails already. I set it up, and it's giving me some dumb issues with the internet. It keeps giving me a yellow exclamation point and is saying that I have limited access, while my desktop is fine, my other laptops are fine. And when I disconnect and reconnect, it fixes the problem. For about two minutes. -.-
What the hell is going on?

I have a Belkin Router, and it is a Asus b960 laptop.

Comment: It gives you that mark from your Wi-Fi icon in your system tray? Or in your browser? 

Or both?

Answer (score 1):

"Limited connectivity" is explained as:

1. Your computer detects that a network is present and operating. So it senses the wireless signal in the case of your laptop (or if it were wired, it detected that the network cable is plugged in)
2. Your computer went unanswered when it requested an IP address.

It's the "unanswered request" that your laptop is telling you about.

The first quick fix would be to reboot your router (I do it by pulling the plug for 30 seconds, then plug it back in) and reboot your laptop after the router is back online.